# SQL Count Unique Deleted Sets

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a simple table in my database that stores sets and values. I want to be able to delete all entries in the database and return the number of distinct sets that were deleted.

```
 create table sets(
      SetId varchar(50)
      Value int
 )
```

If I have two sets each with two values, then the table will be loaded for four entries.

```
 Set1, 0
 Set1, 1
 Set2, 0
 Set2, 1
```

If I delete everything I want to be able to count how many unique SetIds were deleted, so in the example above it should return 2.

Right now I can accomplish this by creating a tempTable that contains the deleted SetIds and then I count distinct

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    SetId varchar(50)
);

delete from Sets
    OUTPUT DELETED.SetId INTO #temp

select count(distinct SetId) from #temp;
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this without having to use a temp table?

Comment: That's basically how I'd do it.

Comment: I would use a table variable.

Comment: Good idea, going to switch to a table variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many rows, and want to avoid temp table (lot of IO) :

```
declare @cnt int;

set xact_abort on
begin transaction

begin try
    select @cnt = count(distinct SetId) from sets;
    delete from sets;    
    commit transaction
end try
begin catch
    rollback;
end catch
```

or :

```
declare @cnt int;

set xact_abort on
begin transaction

begin try
    select @cnt = count(distinct SetId) from sets;
    truncate table sets
    commit transaction
end try
begin catch
    rollback;
end catch
```

Comment: I simplified the use cases to delete everything, but there are cases in which I would only delete a subset of sets. So in that use case I would have to also do a second select and compare it with my original number total distinct.

Comment: You'll have to add WHERE condition to both SELECT and DELETE command.
See what is the best for you, use a temp table, or 2 queries.